# Prove trigonometric function is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, trigonometric-integrals

Is there a way to find an upper bound for $\frac{1}{(\cosh(x)-1)^{1/2}}$ that is Lebesgue integrable on $(0,2]$?

I am struggling to find an upper bound for the function which leads me to think there’s isn’t one. I’ve tried to make the denominator smaller but I can’t really replace the $-1$ by an exponential function without making the denominator negative at certain values in the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINTS:**

Note that we have

$$\sqrt{\cosh(x)-1}=\sqrt 2 \sinh(x/2)$$

As $x\to 0$, $\sinh(x)=O(x)$.  Can you conclude now?

Comment: If the integrand were $\frac1{(\cosh(x)-1)^\alpha}$, then the integral converges for $\alpha<1/2$.

Comment: We can find a useful antiderivative for $\text{csch}(x/2)$ and directly show the integral diverges.  Note $\int \frac1{\sqrt 2 \sinh(x/2)}\,dx=\sqrt{2}\log(\tanh(x/4))+C$

Comment: Yes. I’ve looked into big O notation more and I think it makes some sense

Comment: Pleased to hear!